# Two questions about lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy

1. I would like to remove the outer list of the doubled lists, `[[1,2,3,4,5]]` -> `[1,2,3,4,5]`
2. I want to count the elements in the list, `[[1,2,3,4,2,1,4]]` -> `7`

Comment: Have you actually *tried anything* to achieve either of those aims? Read a tutorial or the documentation? Also, I'd recommend you read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has really easy implementation to do these both.

First question:
[[1,2,3,4]][0]-> [1,2,3,4]

Second question :
len(list) - > returns the length of the list